# Getting the coordinates of a point using the mouse

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

Is there a way to get the coordinates of a point (x and y coordinates) using the mouse on the gazebo client?

Best,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15783/getting-the-coordinates-of-a-point-using-the-mouse/) by [andrestoga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2914/andrestoga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 20 on 2017-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Yes, you can get it with a [GUI plugin](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=gui_overlay&cat=user_input).

[Here](https://github.com/chapulina/gazebo_plugins/blob/e1be58cbfa9fcf79befe7c654eb8c2ba15663bbf/Dominoes/DominoesPlugin.cc#L122-L134)'s an example which gets the mouse position on mouse move.

It uses `gui::MouseEventHandler::AddMoveFilter` and gives it a callback which is called whenever the mouse is moved on the 3D scene.

Then it uses [Scene::FirstContact](http://gazebosim.org/api/8.0.0/classgazebo_1_1rendering_1_1Scene.html#afe0662050a8152eb261a774fdeb03cf1) to get the coordinates of that point in 3D.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shrutheesh R Iyer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26374/shrutheesh-r-iyer/) on 2020-06-02**:
Could you point out which exact example, from the given link, that I should refer to complete the task described in the question

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2020-06-02**:
I updated the link above to the new GitHub repo

**Comment by [msos1115](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/32999/msos1115/) on 2020-09-21**:
Could you be more specific with the instructions ? I am newbie in Gazebo and didn't understand what I should do in order to display the coordinates